# Return Single True/False Value Based on Exact Match to List

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, boolean

Working in Python, I have data that looks like this:

```
myList = [[1,0],
          [0,1],
          [1,1],
          [0,0],
          [0,1]]
```

I would like to use numpy to check if each sublist is equal to a particular list and return a single True or False if the condition is met.

However, if I do this naively, such as:

```
evaluation = np.array(myList)==[1,1]
```

I get a result that looks like this:

```
[[True,False],
 [False,True],
 [True,True],
 [False,False],
 [False,True]]
```

When I really want output that looks like this:

```
[False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False]
```

Any ideas? I know you could do this with a list comprehension and avoid numpy, but it seems there ought to be a vectorized way of doing the above without explicitly looping. The real data is much bigger and having a faster approach would be helpful.

Comment: Does it start as a list?  It takes time to convert it to an array, which could balance out the no-loop time savings.  Test the list comprehension.  It might not be so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `all`:

```
np.equal(myList,[1,1]).all(1).tolist()
```

Or as @pault states:

```
(myList == [1, 1]).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Was going to post `(myList == [1, 1]).all(axis=1)` but it's essentially the same thing as this.